# How to count the frequency of specific Tags from the Stack Overflow data dump's CSV file in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, frequency, stackexchange-api

I recently downloaded the `stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z` file from the [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). Upon extracting the `.7z` file, I was left with a `Posts.xml` file, which I converted to a `Posts.csv` file using the "[stackexchange-xml-converter](https://github.com/SkobelevIgor/stackexchange-xml-converter)" tool on GitHub. The `Posts.csv` file contains all the posts that have been posted on the entire Stack Overflow website. The total size of the `Posts.csv` file is ~67 GB, so it is too large to open in Microsoft Excel, Visual Studio Code, Notepad, etc.

Each **row** in that CSV file (apart form the first row, which is the header row) corresponds to all the data associated with only *one*, particular post. For example, here are just some of the data categories associated with each post: `Title`, `Tags`, `ContentLicense`, `ViewCount`, `CommentCount`, `CreationDate`, etc. Each data category is its own **column** in the CSV file. Here's an image of how it looks like:

[image: Structure of the Posts.csv file from the Stack Exchange Data Dump]

My issue is that I am trying to count the frequency of only *particular tags of interest* from the Posts.csv file, given a list, in Python. For example, suppose I have the following list in Python:

```
tagsOfInterest = ['version-control', 'git', 'git-merge', 'bash', 'microservices']
```

Only in the `Tags` **column** of the CSV file, I would like to count how many times the tag `version-control` appears, how many times the tag `git` appears, how many times the tag `git-merge` appears, etc...

I've been struggling to do this because you'll notice that each row in the `Tags` column is formatted as a continuous string, with each different tag word only separated by a `<>`. For instance, in the first row, a post has been tagged with `<version-control><projects-and-solutions><monorepo>`.

My original attempt involved first reading the `Posts.csv` file, and then adding each row in the `Tags` column to a list, as such:

```
from pandas import *
import csv

# Read data
data = read_csv("Posts.csv")

# Add each row in the "Tags" column to a list:
tags_col = data['Tags'].tolist()
```

and then my idea was to just tokenize each tag word. However, the `Posts.csv` file is so large, that my computer runs out of memory just from creating the list!

**As such, my question is:** given a list of tags that are of interest, e.g., `tagsOfInterest = ['version-control', 'git', 'git-merge', 'bash', 'microservices']`, how can I count the frequency of each element in that list, from the `Tags` column of the `Posts.CSV` file?

Comment: Don't use pandas.  That's just getting in the way, and as you point out, it has to read the whole file into memory.  Use the `csv` module, read it a line at a time, convert the tag column by using `field.lstrip('<').rstrip('>').split('><')`.  That gives you a list of tag names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter()
for row in csv.reader(open('Posts.csv')):
    for tag in row[1].lstrip('<').rstrip('>').split('><'):
        counts[tag] += 1
print(counts)
```

You can use a DictReader if you want, to use `row['Tags']` instead of `row[1]`.

Comment: Thanks! A slight issue with your posted answer: you wrote: split('<>') instead of split('><'). Thankfully you wrote the correct version in your comment to the post.